# Can I access request headers when establishing a WebSocket connection

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

On server side I use `Sec-WebSocket-Key` to identify users and send messages to only those that are correct recipients, so `User A` only receives messages that are address to `User A`.

On client side, though, I'd like to keep this value too, because I want to reuse it if connection is lost to recover session and all pending messages.

Can I somehow read the value of sent headers from a WebSocket client?